# silverlight datagrid - binding each row's style

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml

i've got a silverlight (v2) datagrid where some items are section headers and as such must appear with a different background colour.

i'm trying to do this with the following xaml:

```
        <dg:DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="dg:DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=Background, Mode=OneTime}" />
            </Style>
        </dg:DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

i expect it to bind the Background property of the datagrid row viewmodel to each row's Background property, instead i get a lovely unknown xaml parsing error:

```
{System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException: AG_E_RUNTIME_MANAGED_UNKNOWN_ERROR [Line: 16 Position: 57]
   at System.Windows.Application.LoadComponent(Object component, Uri resourceLocator)
   at Etana.Survey.Silverlight.UserInterface.Views.MaximumProbableLossPage.InitializeComponent()
   at Etana.Survey.Silverlight.UserInterface.Views.MaximumProbableLossPage..ctor()}
```

if i try to explicitly specify "Red" and not try and bind the style, then it works, so I wonder if silverlight would allow me to bind a style like that or if there's some other trick to it.

(the xaml is based on a wpf implementation of this which works fine)

any input would be much appreciated

Comment: another thing that might be worth mentioning is that the ViewModel.Background property is a string.

PS. I am currently setting each row's background by handling the LoadingRow event, but I feel dirty doing that :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your binding to TemplateBinding. eg

```
<dg:DataGrid.RowStyle>
            <Style TargetType="dg:DataGridRow">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{TemplateBinding Background, Mode=OneTime}" />
            </Style>
</dg:DataGrid.RowStyle>
```

Comment: It gave me following Error:
Error Property 'Background' was not found in type 'DataGridRow'

Answer (score 3):

Silverlight as of version number 4 doesn't support bindings in a Setter Value. There is a workaround implemented as an attached property:

[SetterValueBindingHelper](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/11/02/as-the-platform-evolves-so-do-the-workarounds-better-settervaluebindinghelper-makes-silverlight-setters-better-er.aspx)

Comment: thanks for that, sure it will come in handy for people looking for a solution in v4, the question was asked explicitly for v2 though :)

Comment: Exactly what I meant...I came to this post while looking for a solution to that problem and this answer didn't help. Will edit the post.