# How to Highlight Cell in Silverlight DataGrid

Tags: silverlight, c#-4.0, silverlight-4.0

How can I programmatically highlight a DataGrid cell in Silverlight?

Comment: Do you want just to set, say, `BackgroundColor` of a specific cell, or you want to set the color of a cell that shows some specific property of a specific data item? Do you want the highlight to blink for several seconds or to be present whenever the data item is visible in the grid? Do you need a constant color or a data-bound color? The solution strongly depends on your requirements. Please, provide some details.

Comment: Basically just set the bgcolor. I have a chart in my application, and I've written a lineseries_SelectionChanged event for selecting a point on my chart. Given the selected point, I would like to change the background color (more or less highlight) the cell corresponding to the value on a datagrid below the chart. The datagrid contains all of the values on the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to do the following:

1. Add a property (let's name it `IsSelectedInChart`) to your data item class. This property must be `public` and must raise the `INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged` event whenever its value changes.
2. In your `lineseries_SelectionChanged` you should find the data item that corresponds to the selected point and set `IsSelectedInChart` to `true` for it and to `false` for others.
3. Make all instances of `DataGridRow` that exist in the `DataGrid` have a `Binding` set to their `Background` property with `Path=IsSelectedInChart` and a custom `IValueConverter'.

The converter should look like this:

```
public class ValueConverter : IValueConverter
{
  public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
  {
    // TODO: be more careful with nulls and non-expected values
    bool isSelected = (bool)value;
    return isSelected ? new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red) : DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;
  }
}
```

The last step is the trickiest. It may be implemented by overriding the `DataGridRow` `Style`. One approach is shown in https://stackoverflow.com/a/4268159/795861, another one in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/3542179/795861. Check those out.

All these steps are required since you're likely to have a lot of rows in the `DataGrid`. It uses [UI virtualization](http://www.wpfwiki.com/Default.aspx?Page=WPF%20Q4.3&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) which makes it impossible to simple set the `Background` property on the required `DataGridRow` because a single row object is used to present multiple data items. Thus, the only way to make it work with scrolling is binding the background to the data items.

**UPDATE**

To highlight cells in a column that is known at design time, set [DataGridColumn.CellStyle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.controls.datagridcolumn.cellstyle(v=VS.95).aspx) property to that column definition instead of setting the row style:

```
<sdk:DataGrid>
  <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn x:Name="theColumnToHighlight">
      <sdk:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type sdk:DataGridCell}">
          <Setter Property="local:SetterValueBindingHelper.PropertyBinding">
            <Setter.Value>
              <local:SetterValueBindingHelper
                  Type="System.Windows.Controls.Control, System.Windows, Version=2.0.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e"
                  Property="Background"
                  Binding="{Binding IsSelectedInChart, Converter={StaticResource highlighterConverter}}"/>
            </Setter.Value>
          </Setter>
        </Style>
      </sdk:DataGridTextColumn.CellStyle>
    </sdk:DataGridTextColumn>
  </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Should work, although I haven't tried. The xaml does the same as I've suggested for highlighting entire rows, but applies it to cells in a specific column.

Comment: Ugh... So I'm trying to do this:
`<sdk:DataGrid.RowStyle>
                    <Style TargetType="sdk:DataGridRow">
                        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Path=IsSelectedInChart, Converter={StaticResource BackgroundConverter}}" />
                    </Style>
                </sdk:DataGrid.RowStyle> `

but apparently you can't add a converter to property setter?

Comment: Ok, I finally got this to highlight the row using an implementation incorporating `SetterValueBindingHelper`. Can I get it to highlight just the cell I want?

Comment: @John Is it a cell from specific column you know at design-time or the column is determined ar run-time?

Comment: It's a column I know at design time.

Comment: Holy crap! It works! Thank you so much for taking the time to write this all up.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code according to your cell template in DataGrid.
the cellContent give you reference to the cell you want to modify.

```
FrameworkElement cellContent = dataGrid.Columns[0].GetCellContent(dataRow);// datarow is your row where cell intersects.
cellContent .Style = s; // assuming s is the style you want to apply
```